dockerized python application takes a long time to trim a video with ffmpeg
The project trims YouTube videos.
When I ran the ffmpeg command on the terminal, it didn't take too long to respond. The code below returns the trimmed video to the front end but it takes too long to respond. A 10 mins trim length takes about 5mins to respond. I am missing something, but I can't pinpoint the issue.
backend
main.py
import os

from flask import Flask, request, send_file
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin


app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)


current_directory = os.getcwd()
folder_name = "youtube_videos"
save_path = os.path.join(current_directory, folder_name)
output_file_path = os.path.join(save_path, 'video.mp4')

os.makedirs(save_path, exist_ok=True)

def convert_time_seconds(time_str):
    hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, time_str.split(':'))
    total_seconds = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds

    return total_seconds
def convert_seconds_time(total_seconds):
    new_hours = total_seconds // 3600
    total_seconds %= 3600
    new_minutes = total_seconds // 60
    new_seconds = total_seconds % 60

    new_time_str = f'{new_hours:02}:{new_minutes:02}:{new_seconds:02}'

    return new_time_str
def add_seconds_to_time(time_str, seconds_to_add):
    total_seconds = convert_time_seconds(time_str)

    total_seconds -= seconds_to_add
    new_time_str = convert_seconds_time(total_seconds)

    return new_time_str

def get_length(start_time, end_time):
    start_time_seconds = convert_time_seconds(start_time)
    end_time_seconds = convert_time_seconds(end_time)

    length = end_time_seconds - start_time_seconds

    length_str = convert_seconds_time(length)
    return length_str
    
def download_url(url):
    command = [
        "yt-dlp",
        "-g",
        url
    ]
    
    try:
        links = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
        
        video, audio = links.stdout.strip().split("\n")
        
        return video, audio

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Command failed with return code {e.returncode}.")
        print(f"Error output: {e.stderr}")
        return None
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Could not parse video and audio links.")
        return None
    


def download_trimmed_video(video_link, audio_link, start_time, end_time):
    new_start_time = add_seconds_to_time(start_time, 30)
    new_end_time = get_length(start_time, end_time)

    if os.path.exists(output_file_path):
        os.remove(output_file_path)


    command = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-ss', new_start_time + '.00',
        '-i', video_link,
        '-ss', new_start_time + '.00',
        '-i', audio_link,
        '-map', '0:v',
        '-map', '1:a',
        '-ss', '30',
        '-t', new_end_time + '.00',
        '-c:v', 'libx264',
        '-c:a', 'aac',
        output_file_path
    ]
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)

        if result.returncode == 0:
            return "Trimmed video downloaded successfully!"
        else:
            return "Error occurred while downloading trimmed video"
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Command failed with return code {e.returncode}.")
        print(f"Error output: {e.stderr}")


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/trimvideo', methods =["POST"])
@cross_origin()
def trim_video():
    print("here")
    data = request.get_json()
    video_link, audio_link = download_url(data["url"])
    if video_link and audio_link:
        print("Downloading trimmed video...")
        download_trimmed_video(video_link, audio_link, data["start_time"], data["end_time"])
        response = send_file(output_file_path, as_attachment=True, download_name='video.mp4')
    
        response.status_code = 200

        return response
    else:
        return "Error downloading video", 400

    




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')

dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Update the package list and install wget and ffmpeg
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget ffmpeg python3 python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download the latest version of yt-dlp and install it
RUN wget https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest/download/yt-dlp -O /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp \
    && chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp

WORKDIR /app

COPY main.py /app/
COPY requirements.txt /app/


RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


# Set the default command
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]

requirements.txt
blinker==1.7.0
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==3.0.3
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
Werkzeug==3.0.2

frontend
App.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
async function handleSubmit(event, url, start_time, end_time, setVideoUrl, setIsSubmitted){
  event.preventDefault();

  if( url && start_time && end_time){

    try {
      setIsSubmitted(true);
    const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/trimvideo', {
      url: url,
      start_time: start_time,
      end_time: end_time
    },
    {
      responseType: 'blob',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }
  )
    const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'video/mp4' });
    const newurl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);


    setVideoUrl(newurl);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error trimming video:', error);
    }

  } else {
    alert('Please fill all the fields');
  }
}


function App() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState('');
  const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState('');
  const [videoUrl, setVideoUrl] = useState('');
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="app-header">TRIM AND DOWNLOAD YOUR YOUTUBE VIDEO HERE</div>
        <input  className = "input-url"placeholder='Enter url' value={url} onChange={e=>setUrl(e.target.value)}/>
        <div className="input-container">
          <input className="start-time-url" placeholder="start time" value={startTime} onChange={(e)=>setStartTime(e.target.value)}/>
          <input  className="end-time-url" placeholder="end time" value={endTime} onChange={e=>setEndTime(e.target.value)}/>
        
        </div>
        {
          !isSubmitted && <button onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, url, startTime, endTime, setVideoUrl, setIsSubmitted)} className='trim-button'>Trim</button>
        }

        {
         ( isSubmitted && !videoUrl) &&   <div className="dot-pulse"></div>
        }


        {
          videoUrl && <video controls autoPlay width="500" height="360">
          <source src={videoUrl} type='video/mp4'></source>
        </video>
        }

        
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


You could manage docker resources: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/ . Also, mount some volumen to IO operations.

@Mate so it's docker,
mounting volume to IO, would that be adding a volume when running the container?

You could try adding more CPU and a volumen for your "output_file_path".When your application is deployed to production, maybe you have a specific SSD for that, but not for your entire container. Check about --gpus too

If you have some hardware to accelerate ffmpeg, use them. For example see this.
